# How can I grab an array of image files then rescale them in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

What I do right is grab separate columns with single image files and then rescale them. However this time round I would like to grab the array of images and scale the images inside of it then finally store this modified array in the database.

Here is the code:

```
var Image = require("parse-image");
Pars

    e.Cloud.beforeSave("Activity", function(request, response) {
      var imagePromises = [];

      var activity = request.object;

      // you said "image" is always populated, so always add it
      imagePromises.push(createImagePromise(activity, "image1", activity.get("image1").url()));

      // now conditionally add the other promises, using a loop to further reduce repeated code
      for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
          var imageColumn = "image" + i;
          if (activity.get(imageColumn) && activity.get(imageColumn).url()) {
              imagePromises.push(createImagePromise(activity, imageColumn, activity.get(imageColumn).url()));
          }
      }

      // now we have all the promises, wait for them all to finish before we're done
      Parse.Promise.when(imagePromises).then(function () {
          response.success();
      }, function (error) {
          response.error(error);
      });

      function createImagePromise(activity, imageColumn, url) {
          // we want to return the promise
          return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
              url: url
          }).then(function(response) {
            var image = new Image();
            return image.setData(response.buffer);

          }).then(function(image) {
            // Resize the image.
            return image.scale({
              width: 110,
              height: 110
            });

          }).then(function(image) {
            // Make sure it's a JPEG to save disk space and bandwidth.
            return image.setFormat("JPEG");

          }).then(function(image) {
            // Get the image data in a Buffer.
            return image.data();

          }).then(function(buffer) {
            // Save the image into a new file.
            var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
            var cropped = new Parse.File("image.jpg", { base64: base64 });
            return cropped.save();

          }).then(function (cropped) {
              // Attach the image file to the original object.
              activity.set(imageColumn, cropped);
          });
      }



    });
```

I have one field in my database "images" it holds an array of images.

Would appreciate some help here.

Thanks for your time